HST can apparently operate in one-gyro mode, if need be. Why was the Compton Gamma Ray Observatory de-orbited when it lost one of its three gyros?
If HST has been reduced to 2 fully functioning gyros, I read that they plan to turn off one gyro and run in single-gyro mode to save the second functioning gyro. The Compton Gamma Ray Observatory had three gyros and NASA decided to de-orbit the satellite when one gyro failed. Why did NASA not follow this current strategy for CGRO? Parts of CGRO survive re-entry, do they expect any of HST to survive re-entry? Is that the reason?

They are completely different spacecraft with different missions, so there is no reason to assume that one can do something useful in this mode when the other can.

I'll preface this by stating that I thought this was dumb at the time. I will explain why.
The official reason for deorbiting GRO when it was fully operational but one-failure-away from an uncontrolled reentry was that

Due to its large size and estimate of large fragments (1 ton) reaching the ground, "The risk of a public death or serious injury due to an uncontrolled entry from its 28.5° inclination was an estimated 1/1000. The much-improved
risk associated with a controlled entry was an estimated 1/29,000,000."

NASA could not stomach the 1/1000 risk level and so decided to deorbit it after the single failure.
The official NASA allowable risk is 1/10,000 per NASA-STD 8719.14A,
Requirement 4.7-2. So by that criterion, they made the correct decision.
I would also like to point out that GRO had a propulsion system and was therefore capable of purposefully deorbiting itself as long as it could control its attitude.
Sources

ENTRY DEBRIS
FIELD ESTIMATION
METHODS
AND APPLICATION
TO COMPTON
GAMMA RAY OBSERVATORY
DISPOSAL

Spaceref

Spaceflight Now


Now check this out: the risk estimate for an uncontrolled Hubble entry is 1/250. But Hubble is much more loved and takes prettier pictures in the public's eye than GRO did. Also, the original plan was for it to be retrieved by the shuttle and landed for display in a museum.
Now I would like to point out that Hubble never had a propulsion system and was therefore never capable of purposefully deorbiting itself whether it could control its attitude or not (although to be fair, if it lost attitude control, any of the disposal options that involve rendezvous and docking/grappling would be much more difficult.) Hence the original plan for shuttle retrieval.
There are still options on the table for Hubble disposal (detailed in the paper linked below) but as it says, the current baseline option is "do nothing".
Sources

AN EARLY STUDY OF DISPOSAL OPTIONS
FOR THE HUBBLE SPACE TELESCOPE
Pre-STS-107 shuttle manifest showing Hubble Retrieval Mission

Everything above this is factual, but I'll conclude with my opinion, which is that NASA is willing to wait and try to come up with something in panic mode when and if HST irretrievably loses attitude control because it's beloved by the public, but they were not willing to do that with GRO because it was largely unknown to the public.

Hubble is also in a much higher orbit - we likely have decades after loss-of-control to decide what to do, compared to a single year for GRO.

@asdfex HST 340 miles, GRO 317 miles; is that "much higher"?

Wikipedia has GRO with 360 km and HST with 540 km. The latter lost only 20km in 10 years while the first would deorbit in 1-2 years, like trash from the ISS.

@asdfex FWIW, it looks like Hubble will probably reenter within the next 7-10 years. Decay 'speed' (km altitude per year) increases exponentially as your altitude decreases.

@costrom You're right, it lost quite a bit in the past year. I'd expect the rate to be lower again in the next years due to the lower solar activity.

No Hubble, no JWST cooling... no plans for the future.

There's a docking adapter on the back of Hubble, installed by the last Shuttle servicing mission. It's been discussed whether or not it's feasible to service it again with another manned mission.

@Joshua: The Polaris Program has offered to reboost or service Hubble at no charge multiple times. SpaceX, Polaris, and NASA have performed an unfunded study: https://nasa.gov/missions/hubble/nasa-spacex-to-study-hubble-telescope-reboost-possibility/ Not sure what the results are, though. So, it seems to me that there is interest in a boost or service mission by NASA, but no interest in spending a single cent on it.

@JörgWMittag agreed, NASA installed the soft capture device on HST and then cancelled the work to develop the active half of the mechanism.

@JörgWMittag - I think a private HST boost mission is entirely possible within the approximately seven or so years that Hubble has left in orbit. However I would say no way a servicing mission will occur during that time frame. Even just replacing the gyros would require a complex on-orbit capability that will likely not be developed commercially that soon. And for redundancy Hubble already needs more than just new gyros. A boost in a few years however I think is doable, with high PR value even if ultimately it just preserves Hubble for posterity.

@StevePemberton Getting a manned mission to HST to perform a major overhaul in orbit is probably quite a challenge. However,sending a space tug to permanently grapple HST and take over all attitude control is IMHO entirely technically feasible in a few years with current technology,if there's funding.

@TooTea - an unmanned tug to raise Hubble's orbit is probably doable within a few years. However providing attitude control could be complicated as they need to ensure that the thrusters don't contaminate the mirror and instruments or solar panels. Obviously the thrusters would be pointed away from the telescope, but a lot of fairly frequent thrusting would be required on a regular basis, there could be a concern about exhaust materials re-contacting the telescope on subsequent orbits. Or the tug could use reaction wheels, etc to orient the telescope but that's a lot to develop in a few years.

It's possible that GRO needed three gyros to control its attitude during its deorbit burn. The disturbance forces during a thruster firing are much greater than the normal environmental torques (such as aerodynamic and magnetic), and thrust misalignment can quickly put the spacecraft into a tumble. Sensing rapid attitude changes during thruster firings is often one of the reasons to fly a gyro. If you don't have propulsion, these days you can fly using only star trackers as your attitude reference, at least if your pointing requirements are modest.

Besides the safety arguments already discussed in another answer, there was probably also a political angle in play. This has to do with the desire of NASA to convince Russia to get rid of the Mir space station, on the one hand disposing of it safely but also freeing up resources that could then be redirected to ISS. By demonstrating the willingness and ability to do a controlled reentry of a working large NASA satellite, the likelihood of Russia doing the same with Mir might be increased.
By its nature, this kind of thing is unlikely to be widely discussed publicly, but it made it to news reports such as one by SpaceViews which references a CBS article. However, these articles focus on the safety aspects of deorbiting Mir, not the budget implications of its decommissioning for which I did not find references, unfortunately. I heard this discussed by colleagues involved with CGRO when I was at MPE as a graduate student, so this is third hand information at best. There is a collection of news articles related to the deorbiting of CGRO on the MPE web page where more discussion may be found.
CGRO was reboosted twice and the orbit was estimated to last until 2007:

1993: 340 km → 450 km
1997: 440 km → 515 km


Interesting take on it! I forgot to put in my answer that GRO was designed to be refueled and serviced by the shuttle, so they certainly could have fixed it if they wanted to.
